# How to extract values based on criteria in a single column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to extract a unique value from a pivot table from a separate sheet in an Excel workbook based on criteria from a single column.

In the example below, I want to extract the number of trucks sold based on make and color.  I use the following array formula and one condition works (Ford, Yellow) and the other one does not (Dodge, yellow). Am I using the correct formula? Why does it only work for "Ford", but not for "Dodge"? Is this even possible using pivot tables in separate sheets? Thank you in advance.

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$B$9,MATCH(A13,$A$2:$A$9,0)*MATCH(B13,$A$2:$A$9,0),2)}

   A         B  
1          Total Sold   
2 Ford      49  
3   Blue    20  
4   Red     13  
5   Yellow  16  
6 Dodge     37  
7   Blue    30  
8   Red      6  
9   Yellow   1  

Inputs          Outputs
Ford     Yellow   16
Dodge    yellow  #REF!
Ford     Blue     20
```

Comment: have you searched this forum for [excel] two column lookup?

Comment: OH OH OH I know the answer to your question! @Jeeped

Comment: The thing is is that I want to look in one column for one criteria and then look in that same column for another criteria and if both are met, return a value.

Comment: Of course this is doable but the problem of your layout is how does the program know which string means color and which string means the car maker.  You will need to have a reference table for the formula to sort out that criteria.  Two columns will solve your problem right away and it will also make your formula more readable.  BTW, the `MATCH` in your formula will only return the first finding and with multiply together, you get (1 x 4 = 4 , 5 x 4 = 20 and 2 x 1 = 2, the results are the relative position based on your range) and that is why it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you ian0411! What formula would you recommend if i want pull a value from a pivot table based on multiple criteria in a single colum of said pivot table? Sorry, I am not savy with INDEx, MATCH, GETPIVOTDATA functions. So if all of my info is in column A and I want to retrieve a value from Column B that satisfies two criteria from column A (e.g. "Ford" criteria 1, "Blue" criteria 2, returns "20" as an output). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Sold",A1,"Truck",A13,"Color",B13)
```

where `Truck`, `Color` and `Sold` are the column names of your pivot table data.

[image]

Or try something like

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(A13,$A$2:$A$9,0)+MATCH(B13,{"Blue","Red","Yellow"}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mrig! I've applied the INDEX MATCH formula and for sum reason every cell returns the same output. The formula responds to first MATCH criteria, but ignores the second MATCH criteria and just returns the same value. I will try to upload a image soon.

Comment: @KStyles - Okay, upload the image showing formula used, I'll check.

Comment: Thanks again @Mrig! I ended up going the GETPIVOTABLE route and everything works great! Thanks a bunch!